# Remove border beneath selected tab

Tags: jquery, css

Can someone please show me how to remove the border beneath the selected tab? I have tried various ways to no avail.

I have tried adding a negative margin to the tab as well as creating a white border but since the border I am trying to cover is from the content block and not the tab I am at a loss.

EDIT: Here is the simplified HTML with the jquery at the bottom

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#faq_accordion_stu" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content", 
            active: false, 
        });
     });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#faq_accordion_emp" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content", 
            active: false
        });
    });
</script>

<section id="qa-main">  

<div class="container">

<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1"><h2 id="q-header">For Students</h2></li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2"><h2 id="q-header">For Employers</h2></li>
</ul>

    <div id="faq-accordion" class="large-10 columns">

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        <div class="large-12 column">
            <div id="faq_accordion_stu">'
            <h3 class='accordion-q'>Question</h3>
            <div><p class='accordion-a'> Answer </p>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        <div class="large-12 column">
            <div id="faq_accordion_stu">'
            <h3 class='accordion-q'>Question</h3>
            <div><p class='accordion-a'> Answer </p>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div> <!-- end faq-accordion -->
</div> <!-- end container-->

</section> <!-- end section qa-main -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

ul.tabs{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li{
    background: none;
    color: #222;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 2pt solid #EF5A32;
    border-left: 2pt solid #EF5A32;
    border-right: 2pt solid #EF5A32;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

ul.tabs li.current{
    background: #ededed;
    color: #222;
    background-color: white;
}

.tab-content{
    display: none;
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 15px;

}

.tab-content.current{
    display: inherit; 
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })

})
</script>
```

Comment: You sample code isn't clear.  From your writeup you are using PHP and HTML, but you don't provide the CSS or jQuery.  Would it be possible to simplify the question so that you only have HTML/jQuery/CSS?

Comment: Yes, please share the output HTML of the PHP and your associated CSS/JS.

Comment: Please provide the CSS also.

Comment: @AmandaH edit the question and add additional details/code

Comment: @hungerstar I added the css for the tabbed content and the jquery for the tabs.. Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Here is a link to the live page   http://projects.rcktshp.com/faq/

Comment: @hungerstar Have you had any luck on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to have your active tab (`.current`) directly overlap the border of your content container (`#faq-accordion`) DIV while the non active tabs sit below the content container.

To do this there's two steps that need to be done:

1. Position the tabs so that their border and the content container's border overlap. We can do this by pulling the tabs down in some way or the content container up in some way.
2. Make sure the tabs are above the content container in the stack order of elements. By default, elements that appear in the markup later will stack above those that came before them in the markup. We will have to overcome the default stacking.

**Position Tabs**

You can pull up the content container `#faq-accordion` by setting a negative margin on your tabs:

```css
ul.tabs li {
    margin-bottom: -1px; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

**Hide Border**

Then change the stacking order for the currently active/select tab, which hides the content container's border behind your tab.

```css
ul.tabs li.current {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set `border-bottom` to `none` in your `ul.tabs > li.current` css block:

```css
ul.tabs li.current{
    background: #ededed;
    color: #222;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. The border is around the content beneath the tab, so I need something to cover that up somehow when a tab is clicked. I commented on the original post with the link to the page if you want to have a look